# Customizing Spring Data Rest @ManyToMany relationship handling

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

I've got a simple project running Spring-Data-Rest to expose some entities via a Rest API, like this one (simplified, minus Setters/Getters):

```
@Entity 
public class Group {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    ...

}

@Entity 
public class Person{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    ...

}
```

Now, obviously every group can have Persons as members, which can be solved quite easily via `@ManyToMany`. Unfortunately (or typically?) a group membership contains more info than just "is member of". For example, it should also include the information "is admin of" or "is hidden member of".

This leads naturally to an extra entity...

```
@Entity 
public class GroupMember {

    @OneToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(updatable = false)
    private Person member;

    @OneToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(updatable = false)
    private Group group;

    private boolean admin;

    private boolean hidden;

        ...

}
```

Which would not be that bad, but unfortunately leads to a problem... I can no longer simply add members to a group by `POST`ing an `text/uri-list` to (for example) `/groups/1/members`, but I have to instead create a new GroupMember entity by posting to `/groupMembers/` which is, imho, not as comfortable anymore and breaks the cohesion of the Group REST 'tree'.

How can I solve this and allow a simple POST to create a (basic) GroupMember, with default values? Of course I could put a new @RepositoryRestController there that catches any POST request to `/groups/1/members`, but this prevents the list of text/uri-list (since it doesn't seem to support that). I could define a new object, for example with a person id, but this would break the flow, simple posting a link list would be better.

Another way would be to find a way to map the Hibernate @ManyToMany itself without an extra entity... But I don't know such a way...

Comment: spring-data-rest should have an option to allow you to specify the join table object, but then let the uri structure reduce as long as you specify the way each join table additional column reduces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are working with spring data rest and want to handle `text/uri-list` in a custom controller you can pass the value using a parameter of type `Resources` like this:

```
@RequestBody Resources<Object> incoming
```

You obtain the uris by calling `incoming.getLinks()`

You can look at the spring data rest controller as reference - `org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryPropertyReferenceController#createPropertyReference`

Comment: Thanks, that was very helpful. I also found a way to use the UriToEntityConverter, so now I can override my POST/PUT behavior to accept links to person and automatically create GroupMember entities for them.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're right that it is best to have a third entity, `GroupMember` as you proposed.  Can't you still expose an API endpoint that lets you post to `/groups/1/members`? To do you it would seem that you'll need to have business logic in your controller that resolves the appropriate Person(s) and constructs GroupMember instances. This seems to me to be the appropriate place for this business logic to reside.

Comment: As I said, I would prefer to have simply a way to post Persons to the the member list and have GroupMembers created automatically then. Unfortunately, my own BasePathAwareController doesn't even seem able to handle text/uri-list Content-Types (results in a 415), so I cannot even simulate that but would have to create a json representation of that and this would break the flow (because it would be different from the handling of other collections).